# Replacing specific values with others in a .csv, 'tuple' object has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I can find hwo to debugge my code

```
    with open("f_in.csv",'rb') as f, open("f_out.csv", "w") as outputfile:
        for line in f:

    replacements = (
        ("(B)", "0"), ("(D)", "2"), ("Entrée air absente", "2"),
        ("+", "0,5"), ("++", "1"), ("+++", "2"),
        ("(S) +", "0,5"), ("(S) expi. ++", "1"), ("(S) +++", "2"),
        ("100", "0"), ("99", "0"), ("98", "0"), ("97", "0"), ("96", "0"), 
        ("95", "0"), ("94", "1"),("93", "1"),
        ("92", "1"),("91", "1"),("90", "1"),("89", "1"))

    for i, j in replacements.iteritems():
         line = line.replace(i, j)
         outputfile.write(line)`

    for pair in replacements:
        line = line.replace(*pair)
```

I want to replace some value by a specific number for each of them on each line of my csv file

So (B) will be 0, (D) will be 2, + will be 0.5 , ++ will be 1, +++ will be 2 and so  one for the other

**Sample of the csv file :**

```
1277|2013-12-17 16:00:00|100|+|
1360|2014-01-15 16:00:00|(B)|99|++|E
1402|2014-02-05 20:00:00|(D)|99|++|D
1360|2014-01-29 08:00:00|(D)|99||C
1378|2014-01-21 20:00:00|(B)|100||D
```

But with my program i get this error :

```
     for i, j in replacements.iteritems():
     AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: what you might want to do is some substitution using `re.sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a dictionary is preferred in replacements or even translations, you can change the replacements into a dictionary by using the function `dict(replacements)`:

```
replacements = (
        ("(B)", "0"), ("(D)", "2"), ("Entrée air absente", "2"),
        ("+", "0,5"), ("++", "1"), ("+++", "2"),
        ("(S) +", "0,5"), ("(S) expi. ++", "1"), ("(S) +++", "2"),
        ("100", "0"), ("99", "0"), ("98", "0"), ("97", "0"), ("96", "0"), 
        ("95", "0"), ("94", "1"),("93", "1"),
        ("92", "1"),("91", "1"),("90", "1"),("89", "1"))


import re


replvalues = dict(replacements)
regex = "|".join(map(re.escape,replvalues.keys()))
repl = lambda x : replvalues.get(x.string[x.start():x.end()])
with open("f_in.csv") as f:
        for i in f:
            line =  re.sub(regex,repl, i)
            print(line)
```

Now the rest remains the same. ie, you can add the `outputfile.write(line)` etc

Comment: i got this error now  `line = re.sub(r'\(\w\)', lambda x: dict(replacements)[x.string[x.start():x.end()]], i)
KeyError: '(S)'`

Comment: @Zenix sorry never thought you had to replace everything in the replacement tupple. I have edited the code: